# Length of mystery object

Tags: real

What everyday object is ${n}^{-1/4}$ metres long, where $n$ is an integer?

Hint: n=

> 128

Note there may be some cultural dependence here.

Comment: Oh, please don't rewrite the question and pull away the rug under the already given answers. If the question was solved quickly, then that's how it is. There isn't anything sensible you can do about it.

Comment: @M Oehm: it's not pulling a rug from under your solution. It remains great. Leave it as it is, or put it in spoiler. But I am thinking most people won't have read this yet, and I want them to have as much fun as possible.

Comment: Does the modified question gurantee a single/unique answer? If so how?

Comment: The new question is much broader and doesn't feel like it has a single answer... Looking at the current answer there are a multitude of variations of that which are all equally valid...

Comment: @MOehm: In my opinion the first question wasn't great. It wasn't much of a puzzle, it was just do a calculation and recognise the value given - a trivia question at best (I don't think trivia questions are on topic here but may be wrong).

Comment: It’s hardly challenging mathematics. The puzzle had worked fine when I had just posed it at a Christmas party. But the level of puzzling skill in this forum is much greater. I think it is interesting that the -1/4 power of something is part of everyday experience for many people, and the revised expression highlights that better. Thanks for your flexibility

Comment: @Laska: Don't put the answer in the comments! And while one answer might be more commonly experienced the other variations are also seen quite often. And that isn't even counting that there may well be other things that fit this new format. eg n = 1 - the length of a meter ruler. The puzzle really needs something more to point at a single unique answer. Maybe something like "The challenge is to find a answer for this puzzle." which leaves a single answer a little more obviously correct than others (that may not be a good example, I'm not great at riddle type things).

Comment: Firstly, hints are hints to the puzzle **and are supposed to be used as hints** - they are not supposed to provide information vital to the puzzle. What I mean by this is, the puzzle is stupid without the hint. Secondly, I believe this is an incorrect use of the [tag:real] tag - I might be wrong though...

Answer (score 10):

With

> n = 128

We have

> $128^{(-1/4)} = 2^{(-7/4)} \approx 0.297m$ or $29.7cm$

An everyday object of that length is

> An A4 sheet of paper: 21cm wide, and **29.7cm** long

For details, and an explanation why theoretically the length is exactly $n^{(-1/4)}$ see M Oehm's answer

Comment: Please explain why this is so.

Comment: Doesn't it imply that a standard printer's print tray(where papers are loaded) is also an eligible candidate for this, on a lighter vein?

Answer (score 10):

[*I wanted this to be a comment to sousben's answer, but the formulas got a bit unwieldy.*]

The papers of the [A series of ISO 216](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_216) have a edge-length ratio of $\sqrt2:1$, and the long side of $\text A(n-1)$ is the short side of $\text A(n)$. $\text A0$ is defined to have a surface of $1\text m^2$, so

\begin{align}
l\cdot \frac{l}{\sqrt2}&=1\text m^2\\
l^2&=1\text m^2\cdot\sqrt2\\
l&=1\text m\cdot2^\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}

The lengths of the smaller sizes are:

$l_1=l_0/\sqrt{2}^1=1\text m\cdot2^\frac{1}{4}\cdot2^{-\frac{1}{2}}$
$l_2=l_0/\sqrt{2}^2=1\text m\cdot2^\frac{1}{4}\cdot2^{-\frac{2}{2}}$
$l_3=l_0/\sqrt{2}^3=1\text m\cdot2^\frac{1}{4}\cdot2^{-\frac{3}{2}}$
$l_4=l_0/\sqrt{2}^4=1\text m\cdot2^\frac{1}{4}\cdot2^{-\frac{4}{2}}$

The rule

$x^n\cdot x^m=x^{n+m}$

can be used to simplify $l_4$ to

$l_4=1\text m\cdot2^{\frac{1}{4}-2}=2^{-\frac{7}{4}}\text m$

Comment: This is an international standard. So, despite the OP's remark about cultural dependence, no such remark is needed. On the contrary, such a remark would be more appropriate for local alternatives.